# Tab custom file upload button

Tags: html, css, accessibility, tabbing

I've created my own custom file upload button by creating a label and hiding the input element with css. This all works fine, but the problem is I can't use the button by tabbing and enter. I tried adding tabindex=0 to the label. I could then tab to the element ok but there was no action when clicking enter as it is only a label.

Here is the HTML code

```
<label class="custom-file-upload>
<input type="file">
Choose file
</label>
```

and css to hide the default file upload button

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try adding the `tabindex` to the input (even though its hidden). Its an interaction on the file input that opens the browse window...

Comment: @BryceHowitson didnt work. The input element is skipped

Comment: You need to map id of input with label

Comment: @SarveshMahajan this is the equivalent of wrapping the input with a label

Comment: Does the `display:none` cause the skip? You might want to try moving it off screen and setting the `opacity` instead. `input[type="file"]{position: absolute, left: -9000px; opacity:0;}` That way its technically still in the DOM and you should be able to interact with it as if it were visible.

Comment: Yeah it causes the skip. You could do something like this but my label wont be highlighted when tabbed @BryceHowitson

Comment: Right but tabbing to your label and interacting might work correctly without the `display:none`

Comment: It doesnt thats what i'm saying

Answer (score 1):

This can all be achieved with CSS on modern browsers with the added benefit that:

- there is no reliance on JavaScript
- there is no need for a `tabindex`
- it activates with space or enter, both of which are expected behaviours.

The key is to make the input visually hidden (using the `.visually-hidden` class) but still focusable and then use the `+` to link the label (without wrapping the input in the label).

The key part of the example below is `[type="file"]:focus + label`

This lets you change the label styling when the input is selected (it is important that the `<label>` appears **immediately after** the `<input>` in the DOM in order for this to work).

I also included the syntax for applying a `::before` styling on `hover` and `focus` for completeness.

### Example (not a production ready solution)

The example given below was a quick and dirty way of demonstrating how to achieve your goal, it has a couple of accessibility issues that need addressing before putting it into production:-

1. you shouldn't use the same styling for `hover` and `focus` -> hover you should change colour and show the icon, focus add a border and show the icon
2. instead of using a font for the icon you should use an SVG as fonts may break if someone overrides them (i.e. if they have a preferred font due to dyslexia).
3. make sure that you disable animation of the icon entering if people have indicated they prefer reduced movement by using the `prefers-reduced-motion: reduce` media query https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion

Also make sure you associate the label with the input using `for="inputName"` on the label and `id="inputName"` on the input.

```css
.visually-hidden { 
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; 
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
[type="file"] + label {
  background: #f15d22;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1rem 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #99c793;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
[type="file"] + label::before {
  color: #fff;
  content: "\f382";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  font-size: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 130%;
  line-height: 3.3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
[type="file"]:hover + label,
[type="file"]:focus + label{
  background-color: #497f42;
}
[type="file"]:hover + label::before, 
[type="file"]:focus + label::before {
  right: 75%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" />
<input type="file" id="inputName" class="visually-hidden"/>
<label for="inputName">upload</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I may have a little hack that can help. You can use the `focus-within` attribute on your parent element that holds your file input and style it with this

```
parent:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, I had my input inside the parent element like you described but made it an invisible 1x1 pixel. This worked great until someone tabbed onto the input and nothing got highlighted. This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your code something in this manner

```
<input id="file-upload" type="file">
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload>Choose file</label>
```

CSS for input and change css for label accordingly using sibling selector

```
input[type="file"] {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can tab to the invisible input file but my label isnt highlighted

Answer (score 0):

With labels you need to trigger click on keyboard events for enter

```
<label for ="file-upload1" tabindex="0" class="custom-file-upload">
<input type="file" id="file-upload"/> Choose file
</label>
```

CSS

```
input[type="file"]{
  display:none;
}
```

JQuery Code

```
$('.custom-file-upload').on('keyup',function(event){
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $('#file-upload').trigger('click');
  }
})
```